# SSH - request public key instead of fingerprint?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-host-key

When initiating a connection by SSH to a server not known in the hosts file, it's common to get a message such as the following:

`The authenticity of host '[IP address]' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is [checksum].
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`

Is there a way to request the server to present the whole public key instead of the fingerprint?

Comment: Not what you asked, but [SSH certificates](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssh-ca-to-validate-hosts-and-clients-with-ubuntu) are a great solution to this.

Comment: Briefly, what problem would you say they solve?

Comment: Knowing whether the trust the server's key. You have a CA key (just for your organisation) that you sign all your server keys with. Then you install the CA public key on all your clients. They can then connect to any SSH server and automatically verify the key, just like when you connect to an https web site.

Comment: No. There is no such option in OpenSSH. What problem *you* are trying to solve? The fingerprint is safe representation of the server host key which should be human-readable, unlike the key itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ssh-keyscan` to get the information you want.  It's primarily designed for gathering public keys over an initial trusted network connection and automatically adding them into the `known_hosts` file.